# Google Sheets responds with success but does not record values

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I do not get errors when submitting via Postman and in fact gets this reply

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "row": 2
}
```

But when I check my google sheets, the values are not recorded. This is my sheet:

[image]

And this is my code:

```
var scheduleSheet = 'Schedules'
var stationSheet = 'ReloadingSites'

var scriptProp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()

function intialSetup() {
  var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  scriptProp.setProperty('key', activeSpreadsheet.getId())
}

function doPost(e) {
   var lock = LockService.getScriptLock()
   lock.tryLock(10000)
   
   try {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(scriptProp.getProperty('key'))
    var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(scheduleSheet)

    var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0]
    var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1

    var newRow = headers.map(function(header) {
      return header === 'timestamp' ? new Date() : e.parameter[header]
    })

    Logger.log(newRow)
    sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])

    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'success', 'row': nextRow }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }

  catch (e) {
    return ContentService
      .createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ 'result': 'error', 'error': e }))
      .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)
  }
  
  finally {
    lock.releaseLock()
  }
}
```

Where is my error?

Comment: What does the `console.log(newRow)` display before the line `sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, newRow.length).setValues([newRow])`?

Comment: There is no conosole.log in appscript sir.

Comment: Yes there is. Check the [Logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging) and [console](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/console#log) Class pages.

Comment: Sorry... I saw it. I tried it but it's not logging anything sir. Please see my update

Comment: `View > Executions`, click the execution. Logger.log won't display for a web app.

Comment: It says "No logs are available for this execution
For recent executions there may be some delay in log availability."

Comment: Please retry and post the log. Without it we can't start to debug your script.